¿Cómo funciona este código sobre hilos?
En clase estamos revisando el tema de hilos y me tope con un ejemplo que combina varios temas que hemos visto hasta ahora, como bloques estáticos, colecciones y llamar a un método dentro de otro. Así que me di a la tarea de tratar de entender a fondo su funcionamiento (el ejercicio solo involucra modificar una única línea y dejar todo lo demas como esta) pero yo creo que me serviría como repaso.
Ya intenté leerlo una y otra vez y realizar varios debugs pero aun así no me queda claro que hace (o para que). Una disculpa si mi duda no es muy concreta, en si lo que estoy buscando es una explicación sencilla.
Este es el código:
public class WeirdExample4 {

    public static int threadCount = 10;
    public static int[] testArray = new int[10];

    //Bloque estatico
    static {
        for (int i = 0; i < WeirdExample4.testArray.length; i++) {  //Aqui por ejemplo porque esta línea está asi: "WeirdExample4.testArray.length" en vez de solo "testArray.length"

            testArray[i] = i; 
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        StringBuilder expectedResult = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 10 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            expectedResult.append(i).append(" ");
        }

        initThreads();

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i : testArray) {
            result.append(i).append(" ");
        }
        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println((result.toString()).equals(expectedResult.toString()));
    }

    public static class SortThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sort(testArray);
        }
    }

    public static void initThreads() throws InterruptedException {

        List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>(threadCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
            threads.add(new SortThread());
        }
        for (Thread thread : threads) {
            thread.start();
        }
        for (Thread thread : threads) {
            thread.join();
        }
    }

    public static void sort(int[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
                if (array[i] < array[j]) {
                    int k = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[j];
                    array[j] = k;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Esta es la salida en pantalla:

9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
true


Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo crees que funciona tal código.

Es absurdo. Crea threadCount hilos para ordenar un arreglo lo suficientemente pequeño como para ser completamente ordenado antes que los siguientes hilos alcancen a crearse. Está haciendo doble trabajo. Es un mal ejemplo de hilos. Sería más interesante si durmiera los hilos luego de cada iteración.

lo que preguntas no tiene sentido con el comentario que tienes en el codigo... pero la linea que preguntas es lo mismo que this. osa de esta clase: this.testArray o de esta clase WeirdExample4.testArray es casi lo mismo

El programa principal está levantando threadCount hilos (10 en el caso que se ilustra).
Estos hilos están implementados en la clase SortThread, y lo que hacen es ordenar mediante el método de la burbuja un array. Por cierto, una ordenación bastante ineficiente, ya que continúa aunque no haya hecho ningún cambio en la última pasada del array.
El array que se está facilitando a todas las clases SortThread aparentemente se define testArray en la clase principal (WeirdExample4): este array se está inicializando con los valores 0...9.
Al iniciar las tareas, éstas se lanzan en el método initThreads y cumplen los tres pasos básicos que deben darse al lanzar un hilo:

creamos la clase hilo
la iniciamos ejecutando su método start()
finalmente, en el programa principal esperamos a que termine ejecutando el método join()

Es curioso que todos los hilos, por lo que puedo observar, están modificando el array simultáneamente, lo que puede provocar problemas de concurriencia,
máxime cuando el array no ha sido declarado como volátil ni tampoco como un array que soporte concurrencia.

Si pones un print y verás que el primer hilo comienza y termina antes que los demás

Eso no es cierto, acabo de poner un print antes y después del sort, y he realizado un cambio para que cada hilo tenga un número. En mi máquina unas veces se observa que comienza el 4 el primero y termina el 1 el primero. En otros casos comienza el 7 y termina el 5 el primero, es aleatorio. Creo que te refieres al join(): si pones un print antes del join, el programa principal parará más tiempo al llegar al primer hilo; pero en los sucesivos el hilo ya habrá finalizado (no hay que esperar por una tarea finalizada) y por lo tanto irá mucho más rápido

Añado otro dato: he subido el tamaño del array a 10000 elementos y los errores que indicaba que podían existir al ordenar concurrentemente el mismo array se manifiestan: aparecen números duplicados

Mira esto https://onecompiler.com/java/42sfny42y

Cuando el array tiene 10 elementos, todos comienzan y finalizan en orden: la ejecución no evidencia que el primero tarde más o menos que el resto. Al subir el número de elementos del array a 10000 se observa que el comienzo es secuencial pero la finalización de los hilos es aleatoria. Tampoco entiendo a dónde queremos llegar con este debate, ya que lo que la pregunta solicita es que se explique qué está haciendo el código indicado
